# OCaml function with variable number of arguments

Tags: function, ocaml, variadic-functions

I'm exploring "advanced" uses of OCaml functions and I'm wondering how I can write a function with variable number of arguments.

For example, a function like:

```
let sum x1,x2,x3,.....,xn = x1+x2,+x3....+xn
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

With a bit of type hackery, sure:

```
let sum f = f 0
let arg x acc g = g (acc + x)
let z a = a
```

And the (ab)usage:

```
# sum z;;
- : int = 0
# sum (arg 1) z;;
- : int = 1
# sum (arg 1) (arg 2) (arg 3) z;;
- : int = 6
```

Neat, huh? But don't use this - it's a hack.

For an explanation, see [this page](http://mlton.org/Fold) (in terms of SML, but the idea is the same).

Comment: I wouldn't use this because passing an int list is the better way. But very nice use of higher level functions and continuation passing style.

Comment: BTW this is how the [Printf](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Printf.html) module is implemented

Answer (score 11):

OCaml is strongly typed, and many techniques used in other (untyped) languages are inapplicable. In my opinion (after 50 years of programming) this is a very good thing, not a problem.

The clearest way to handle a variable number of arguments of the same type is to pass a list:

```
# let sum l = List.fold_left (+) 0 l;;
val sum : int list -> int = <fun>
# sum [1;2;3;4;5;6];;
- : int = 21
```

Comment: "many techniques used in other (untyped) languages are inapplicable." Are you saying variadic functions aren't possible in strongly typed languages?

Comment: A list does not allow you to pass variables with different types.
I.e.: on Clojure:
`user=> (defn greet [& arg] (str arg))`