# Function invocation with arbitrary type

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, functional-programming, ocaml

I am trying to implement a function `f` so that when called like the following:

```
(((f 1) 2) 3) ()
```

It returns the sum of 1, 2, and 3, which is 6. Only when it's invoked with a Unit argument `()` that the computation happens and the sum returned.

In Javascript (ES6), for instance, it could be implemented as such:

```
let f = (v, acc = 0) => {
  if (typeof v === 'undefined') return acc;
  return next => f(next, acc + v); 
};

f(1)(2)(3)();   // 6
```

However in Ocaml with strong typing it isn't as clear, or at least not as terse.

**EDIT**: Here is my attempt using variant types:

```ml
type any =
  | Nothing
  | Number of int

type result =
  | Int of int
  | Fn of (any -> result)


let rec sumfun ?(acc=0) v =
  match v with
  | Nothing -> Int(acc)
  | Number n -> Fn(fun next -> sumfun ~acc:(acc+n) next)

let _ =
  let a = sumfun (Number 2) in
  match a with
  | Int n -> print_int n
  | Fn f ->
     let b = f (Number 3) in
     match b with
     | Int n -> print_int n
     | Fn f ->
        let c = f Nothing in
        match c with
        | Int n -> print_int n
        | Fn f -> ()
```

As it is the calls to `sumfun` are super hairy. Is there a better, less verbose or more idiomatic way than this?

Comment: Well in Ocaml you shouldn't write such a function…

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26475765/1048572 https://stackoverflow.com/q/35968221/1048572 should suffice as pointers though :-)

Comment: isn't that the nature of strongly typed languages - you should never have to do that?

Comment: My advice is to work with the OCaml type system, not against it. So you don't want a function like this :-) You can use a variant type to collect tagged values of different types. That's what you might use in idiomatic OCaml.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, the general advice would be not to do such a thing. Your particular example would naturally be expressed with a list:

```
let sum = List.fold_left (+) 0

let n = sum [1; 2; 3]
```

I don't see any advantage in using the complicated construction you show, regardless of types.

But to answer your original question anyway, the best you can do probably is providing custom operators for application, e.g.

```
let ($) f x = match f (Number x) with Fn f' -> f' | _ -> assert false
let ($$) f () = match f Nothing with Int n -> n | _ -> assert false

let n = sumfun $ 1 $ 2 $ 3 $$ ()
```

(I tried to use GADTs to avoid the `assert false` there, but apparently they interact badly with optional arguments.)

But to repeat the point: Don't.

Answer (score 2):

I completely agree with Andreas, but I have another solution with GADTs:

```ml
type 'a args = | M : int -> ('b args -> 'b) args
               | O : int -> (unit -> int) args

let rec f : type a. a args -> a = function
  | M n -> (function | M m -> f (M (m + n))
                     | O m -> fun () -> n + m)
  | O n -> fun () -> n
```

You need to distinguish partial application and the final one, so here we have two kinds of arguments: `M` for meta and `O` for object (I do not know why I chose these definitions).

So, now we have:

```ml
# (((f (M 1)) (M 2)) (O 3)) ();;
- : int = 6
```

Or with `$` notation:

```ml
let ($) f i = f i

# f $ (M 1) $ (M 2) $ (O 3) $ ();;
- : int = 6
```

What's important here is that "wrong" expressions (like `f $ (M 1) $ (M 2) $ ()`) are rejected by type checking at compile time and not with exceptions at runtime.

Comment: I had to go with Andreas' answer as the correct one but I really appreciate this attempt.